Internal function call in FastAPI / Parameter that I can set only inside the FastAPI app
I wrote my own session logic and use the following decorator to check the request:
def require_session(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs['request']
        session_key = request.headers.get('X-Session-Key')
        if session_key is not None:
            session = Session.check(session_key)  # Check in db
            if session is not None:
                return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        raise exc.access_denied()
    return wrapper

And I use it like this
import fastapi as fa

employees_router = fa.APIRouter(default_response_class=fa.responses.JSONResponse)

@employees_router.get('/{id}')
@require_session
async def get_employee(request: fa.Request, id: int) -> EmployeeDBSchema:
    employee = Employee.get_or_none(id=id)
    if employee is None:
        raise exc.instance_by_field_not_found(Employee, id)
    return employee

I simply check for the session key first in the headers and then in the database. And everything works fine until I try to call these methods inside other methods.
@administrators_router.post('')
@require_session
async def create_administrator(request: fa.Request, data: AdministratorSchema) -> AdministratorDBSchema:
    data_dump = data.model_dump()
    if isinstance(data_dump['employee'], int):
        await get_employee(request, data_dump['employee'])  # Inner call
    try:
        admin = Administrator.create(**data_dump)
    except pw.IntegrityError as e:
        raise exc.integrity(e)
    return admin

This results in the session being checked twice. How can I avoid the second session check?
I was looking for something like "Parameter that I can set only inside the fastapi app" to just define an additional parameter inner_call=false that tells the decorator not to check the session, but I didn't find anything.
The second solution is to separate the endpoint from its implementation like this:
@employees_router.get('/{id}')
@require_session
async def get_employee(request: fa.Request, id: int) -> EmployeeDBSchema:
    return get_employee_impl(id)

async def get_employee_impl(id: int) -> EmployeeDBSchema:
    employee = Employee.get_or_none(id=id)
    if employee is None:
        raise exc.instance_by_field_not_found(Employee, id)
    return employee

And just call get_employee_impl where I want to avoid the session check, but rewriting all the functions can take a lot of time. Also, this solution doesn't seem very clean to me.

Use contextvar, which can store variable in a request context
modify your code like:
from contextvars import ContextVar
ctx_session = ContextVar('ctx_session', default=None)

def require_session(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if ctx_session.get() is None:
            request = kwargs['request']
            session_key = request.headers.get('X-Session-Key')
            if session_key is not None:
                session = Session.check(session_key)  # Check in db
                if session is not None:
                    ctx_session.set(session)
                    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
            raise exc.access_denied()
        else:
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

